# Don´t show y value for specific x matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to generate a plot containing multiple boxplots. But in addition on one x value, there should be "free space".

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

series1 = [[0.1,0.2,.3], [0.2,0.3,0.5], [0.2,0.4,0.5], [0.1,0.3,0.5]]
plt.boxplot(series1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Basically the above image, without showing the boxplot at x=3.

Comment: There is a parameter `positions` where you can set the desired x-positions, e.g. `plt.boxplot(series1, positions=[1, 2, 4, 5])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

series1 = [[0.1,0.2,.3], [0.2,0.3,0.5], [0.2,0.4,0.5], [0.1,0.3,0.5]]

del series1[2]
plt.boxplot(series1, positions = [1,2,4])
plt.show()
```